# How to start/stop third part services during starting/stoping WAMP server?

Tags: php, wamp

I have installed several services for web apps (memcache, tomcat and mongodb).
They works fine, but I should start or stop it manually.

For example (cmd): memcached.exe -d start

I need these services only during running WAMP server, so i don't want to run these services during starting windows...

How to run these commands automaticaly duiring starting and stoping WAMP server (do the same thing with third part services as it do to Apache and Mysql services)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found right answer yet, but I have some lifehack (on memcache example):

1. Install any app as a windows service. (cmd: memcached.exe -d install)
2. Config your service: Start > Manualy (standart windows services routine)
3. Creat file "start.bat" and write down starting commands for all your services and launche it after starting WAMP server. (net start memcached)
4. Creat file "stop.bat" and write down stoping commands for all your services and launche it after stoping WAMP server. (net stop memcached)

It's not a solution, but save some time and resources for you.

Does someone knows how to run these files (start.bat & stop.bat) automaticaly during starting and stoping WAMP server?